# Solve $x = -(e^{Bx}z-y)Be^{Bx} z$ for $x$ or show existence or uniqueness of solution.

Tags: exponential-function, matrix-equations, transcendental-equations

Let $ B,y,z \in \mathbb R$. Is it possible to solve the equation
\begin{align}
x = -(e^{Bx}z-y)Be^{Bx} z
\end{align}
for $x \in \mathbb R$? Or can one show that a unique solution $x \in \mathbb R$ exists?

My claim for uniqueness stems from observing several Matlab plots of the right-hand-side, for different cases of $B,y,z$. However, it seems difficult for me to prove it.

(More generally, I consider this equation for a matrix $B$ and vectors $z,y$.)

Comment: If $z,y$ are vectors and $B$ is a matrix, wouldn’t $x$ be a matrix/vector too? Also, it would be good to know if a series solution to the equation is wanted more then showing that there is a unique solution.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I think $x$ would still be a scalar if you write the equation as $$x=-(e^{Bx}z-y)^TBe^{Bx}z.$$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ I guess it is not possible to solve this equation for $x$, and hence, I am just interested in uniqueness.
x is still a number, as it was answered correctly.